# translate category attributes in magento backend

Tags: attributes, magento, categories, translate

I can translate product attributes in the backend by editing the attribute label.
Is it possible to do the same for category attributes?
Is there another way to translate them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the value of a category's attributes for one store at a time by picking that store from the "Choose Store View" drop-down. This restricts your changes to the store you are editing.

Many things can be translated on both the frontend and backend with [inline translation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/).

Comment: I've edited eav_attribute and it seems to work. I think that what happens when you edit product attributes on the backend. Magento should have editing options for all attributes not just product attributes.

Comment: Editing the database directly risks making a harmful change (albeit a small risk if you know what you're doing). You can provide your own translations in a simple CSV file in `/app/locale/*` and then pick your language from the selection at the bottom of any admin page.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick your language from the selection at the bottom of any admin page". If magento is not calling the translate function the CSV won't help.